# compareTo Error: Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int

Tags: java, compareto

Not sure how to get the `compareTo` to not give error.

Very lost. Tried changing multiples lines of code.

```
public voide addValue(int newNumber){
int index = 0;

while ((index < numbers.size()) && (numbers.get(index.compareTo(newNumber) ==-1))
      index++;

    numbers.add(index, NewNumber);      
}
```

I expected it to be able to have no issues with `compareTo(newNumber)`.

> Error Message: "Cannot invoke `compareTo(int)` on the primitive type
>   int"

Answer (score 6):

> "Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int"

You have to understand: the **primitive** type `int` isn't a reference type like `Integer`. You can't call **methods** on primitive values. When you want to compare two ints, you can simply do `index < newNumber` for example.

Alternatively, you could use that static method [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int))  of the Integer class, like: `Integer.compare(index, newValue)`. But as said: you don't need methods to compare primitive values, you can directly do that "in place".

Note: in other languages, like Kotlin, there is no such difference. There you only have Int objects, and call methods on those. But java makes that distinction. So study it, and learn how to use which approach.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I can't believe what I originally wrote here.

Can you not just use a relational comparison operator here?

```java
(firstNum < secondNum) // This will return a boolean value of true or false.
```